# How do I automatically have a command run from my Windows 10 command prompt when I log in?

Tags: service, windows-10, command, command-prompt

I'm using Windows 10.  When I first login, I launch a command window using

```
cmd
```

and then run a service using

```
myserv -a
```

I would like all this to happen automatically after I login.  How do I configure this in Windows 10 when I am not an admin user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. First, you need to create a batch file for your commands. Here are the steps to do it:

   - Right-click anywhere on your desktop, go to `New > Text Document`.
   - Open the new text document, and type in the following commands:

```bash
@echo off
cd "C:\Path\to\folder"
cmd /c "myserv -a"
```

- Click on `File > Save As`, change the `Save as type` to `All Files`, and save it with any name but with an extension of `.bat` (for example, `autoStart.bat`).

***IF ADMIN REQUIRED SKIP STEPS #2 and #3 see below for admin privileges***

2. To make this batch file run automatically when you log in, you have to place it in the `Startup` folder. Here are the steps to do that:

   - Press `WIN+R` to open the `Run` dialog box.
   - Type `shell:startup` and hit `Enter` to open the `Startup` folder.
   - Simply drag-and-drop (or copy and paste) your batch file into this folder.
3. Now, every time you log in to your Windows 10, the batch file will run automatically, which, in turn, will run cmd and then your service.

Since the service you're trying to run requires elevated privileges, it may be best to request that an admin user set up the automatic task, or grant your user account the necessary permissions.

Admin users can setup tasks with elevated privileges via the Task Scheduler:

1. Open Task Scheduler (`Start` > `Windows Administrative Tools` > `Task Scheduler`).
2. Select `Create Basic Task`.
3. Input a `Name` and `Description` then click `Next`.
4. Select `When I log on` then click `Next`.
5. Choose `Start a program` then click `Next`.
6. Click `Browse` to find and select your batch file. Then click `Next` and `Finish`.
7. Right-click the task you just created, select `Properties`.
8. In the `General` tab, check `Run with highest privileges`.
9. Click `OK`

Comment: The use of `cmd /c` is not needed here. Just use `[path_to_]myserv.exe -a`

Answer (score 9):

If you're not an admin user, this is impossible: [link to statement from Windows forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1076069/task-scheduler-how-to-to-grant-non-admin-users-the)

However, ***if you were to get admin permissions***, here is how you would do it:

1. Open Run. You can do this with `Win + R` or by typing Run into the search bar.
2. Once Run is open (should be a small window in the bottom left corner), type `taskschd.msc`. This opens **Task Scheduler**
3. In Task Scheduler, click "Create Basic Task"
4. After naming your task, choose "When I Log In", then "Start a Program"
5. Click "Browse", then find `cmd.exe`, located usually in `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`
6. Add `/k myserv -a` to the "Add arguments (optional)" field.

Your computer should then run your program on launch, then promptly close the command prompt panel.

Comment: You can open cmd using the Run too: press `Win+R` and then type `cmd`, so command prompt will open.
Also, if you need to open powershell, type `powershell` in the Run window. And type `wt` if you need to open Windows Terminal (you should download it in Microsoft Store). Windows Terminal is a terminal with tabs where you can use linux terminal and windows cmd and powershell.

Answer (score 4):

if you need this to run "at logon" you don't need admin privileges, just create a shortcut in your Startup folder (%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup) to:

```
cmd /c "myserv -a"
```

[refer](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-uk/000124550/how-to-add-app-to-startup-in-windows-10)

Comment: This was my thought too - create a .bat file in that Startup folder. Heck here are two links that discuss it:
https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000322.htm
https://www.shellhacks.com/run-batch-file-bat-on-startup-in-windows/

Comment: The use of `cmd /c` is not needed here. Just use `[path_to_]myserv.exe -a`

Answer (score 4):

Add a registry key of type `REG_SZ` to `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`
`myserv=[path_to_]myserv.exe -a`

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys

> Use Run or RunOnce registry keys to make a program run when a user logs on. The Run key makes the program run every time the user logs on, while the RunOnce key makes the program run one time, and then the key is deleted. These keys can be set for the user or the machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a batch file with the following:

```
@echo off
myserv -a
```

Save the file as `[name].bat` and put it in the start-up folder.
The start-up folder is in `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`. You can run `start "" "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"` in cmd to open the folder.

When the user logs in, anything in that start-up folder will be automatically executed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this way to run your commands automatically
create a batch file with commands you need, than type `Win+R`, then write `shell:startup` (the startup folder will open in explorer will open) and create a label to your batch file in this folder.

If you need to show files, that will run automatically, you can use [autorunsc](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns#download).
It is a good program to show it.